# How to bulk copy multiple csv files from blob to mutliple sql database tables with data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I am trying copy different csv files in blob storage into there very own sql tables(I want to auto create these tables). Ive seen alot of questions but I haven't seen any that answer this.

Currently I have a getmetadata function that grabs a list of child items to get the name of the files and a foreach loop but from there I don't know how to have them sent to different tables per file.

Comment: Does the file names correspond to the table names?

Comment: yes the file names will to the table names

Comment: Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi @2tone_tony. Please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated:**
When I run it for a 2nd time. It will add new rows into the table.
[image]

---

I created a simple test and it works well. This is my csv file stored in Azure Data Lake.
[image]

Then we can use pipeline to copy this csv file into Azure SQL table(auto create these tables).

1. At `GetMetaData1` activity, we can set the dataset of the folder containing csv files
   [image]
   And select `First row as header` at the dataset.
   [image]

2.At `ForEach1` activity we can foreach the file list via expression `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`.
[image]

3.Inside `ForEach1` activity, we can use `Copy data1` activity with the same data source as `GetMetaData1` activity. At `source` tab, we can type in **dynamic content** `@item().name`. We can use `@item().name` to get the file name.
[image]

4. At `sink` tab, we should select `Auto create table`.
   [image]
   In the Azure SQL dataset, we should type in `schema name` and **dynamic content** `@replace(item().name,'.csv','')` as its table name. Because this information is needed to create a table dynamically.
   [image]
5. The debug result is as follows:
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Hi @joseph - will the copy activity succeed if the tables already exist - means when you run it for a 2nd time?

Comment: @azuresnowflake1 It will insert new rows into table. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: High sorry for the really late reply but this worked thanks!