# Bulk copy multiple csv files from Blob Container to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-data-factory, bulkinsert

Environment:

MS Azure:
Blob Container, multiple csv files saved in a folder. This is my source.
Azure Sql Database. This is my target

Goal:
Use Azure Data Factory and build a pipeline to "copy" all files from the container and store them in their respective tables in the Azure Sql database by automatically creating those tables.

How do I do that? I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011176/how-to-bulk-copy-multiple-csv-files-from-blob-to-mutliple-sql-database-tables-wi) but I just end up having tables incorrectly created in the database, where table is created with a single column having same name as the table name.

I believe I followed the instructions from that link pretty must as they are.

Comment: You said that the table name is included in the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My CSV file is as follows, one column contains the table name.
[image]

The previous steps will not be repeated,it is the same as the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013767/13979487).

1. At Step3 inside the Foreach activity, we should add a Lookup activity to query the table name from the source dataset.
   [image]
2. We can declare a String type variable `tableName` pervious, then set the value via expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.tableName`.
   [image]
3. At sink setting of the Copy activity, we can key in `@variables('tableName')`.
   [image]
4. ADF will auto create the table for us.
   [image]
5. The debug result is as follows:
   [image]

Comment: I feel really stupid. Your original solution in the other post works perfectly. Turns out my source files had table name in the first row, which is why I was getting a single column similar to the table name. I apologize. I should delete this post. But I truly thank you for your response and your solution in the original post. I want to reach out directly but I couldn't find a way and ended up creating a new thread. Again thank you and also apologies!!!

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working. Under the assumptions in my answer, it works well, hope you can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you! :)

Comment: I will do that. Thank you :)